# Tricolour nonogram

Tags: nonogram

Don't mind me, just dropping this nonogram here.

> [image]

Note that cells filled with different colours do not need to have a gap between them.

Comment: The grid is 30 columns by 40 rows (don't mind me, just dropping that info here).

Comment: There is a problem with this - row 26 appears too wide for the grid given, unless a color change does not require an unfilled space between the two colors. (I'm used to monochrome nonograms, where each number represents a contiguous string of colored cells, with at least one uncolored cell between each string.)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Added a note.

Comment: Well I was making good headway, plugging away in Paint, when apparently I made a mistake. Then I found out that Paint only lets you undo so many previous steps. T_T

Comment: @Somebody ouch! (then again... Paint? ^^ time to go gimp or whatever supported software)

Comment: if I wasn't on a work computer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is right! Doing this by hand was a real pain :)

> [image]

Comment: you had 5 1 1 in the 5 1 2 column...

Comment: Aha! I missed a row when I was finishing. 

And I was about to say the same to you, I thought I got mine in just before yours!

Comment: you should get the check since you were the first to get the right answer. well done and good game!

Comment: thanks! I do nonograms on break at work all the time, so it was nice to catch one in time to do it here too :)

Answer (score 12):

> [image]

oops just realised some mistakes:

1) row 252: 5 chunk should shift right for one block

2) first row of FRANCE: first grey block should shift right for one block

Answer (score 6):

Here is the nonogram completed:

> Very much tricolour indeed ;)
>  [image]

Comment: Not necessarily, rot 13(va gur pbyhza gung fgnegf terl 4, oyhr 1, terl 3, oyhr 1, gur obggbz fdhner va lbhe vzntr pbhyq or oyhr.)

Comment: Note that cells filled with different colours don't need to have a gap between them.